# 301 Redirection from no-www https to www https in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

after an analysis of the woorank site, i have this result

[image]

So i try to add a 301 redirection for https://monsite.com to https://www.monsite.com

```
301 https redirects to without WWW
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But it's doesnt work. For information, i use the default htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Les directives (lignes) entre « BEGIN WordPress » et « END WordPress » sont générées
# dynamiquement, et doivent être modifiées uniquement via les filtres WordPress.
# Toute modification des directives situées entre ces marqueurs sera surchargée.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Thnaks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```bash
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This rule is only redirecting to `https` site, not adding `www`. You can use this rule to do both redirections in a single rule:

```bash
## add www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your `mod_rewrite` rules.

---

Your full .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: I should write like this ?

Comment: I have updated my answer with full .htaccess, test it and let me know.

Comment: I try it and have a internal server error

Comment: For internal server error, you need to check Apache server `error.log` for any typo or syntax error.

Comment: i forgot to precise, it's a CentOs server. In /var/log/httpd/error_log, i have no error

Comment: An internal server error is always logged in Apache error log. Btw this code works pretty well on my local Apache

Answer (score 0):

I have often found that plugins handle this better than trying to do it manually with the .htaccess file, so you could try that as an alternative.

Here are some options in this article:
https://cheapsslsecurity.com/p/best-http-to-https-wordpress-plugins/